# Foreign Key doesn't stop me entering data MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table which has one column as a foreign key joining to another table. 
It's a cricket question where I have a table called Fixtures and another called Inning.

Inning table has a FixtureId column relates to the Fixture table.

I would expect that If i do a insert on the inning table using a FixtureId that doesn't relate to a Fixture then it would error but this isn't the case...

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: What is the table type - MyISAM or Innodb?  My guess would be MyISAM, which doesn't enforce foreign keys.  If Innodb, is the foreign key constraint in place?  Both will be answered if you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the InnoDB storage engine when creating the table. Other storage engines will simply ignore foreign key constraints. ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html))

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
     id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE b (
     id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     a_id INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO b (id, a_id) VALUES(NULL, 1);
```

The above insert fails with:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...

Comment: In addition to that, the inline `REFERENCES` keyword is ignored by InnoDB.  You **must** use the `FOREIGN KEY` syntax instead: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Wow, thank you. Coming from PostgreSQL, this was driving me nuts. It should be noted that MyISAM is the *default* engine, and thus foreign keys won't work as expected. (You'd think it could throw a warning or something. “I see you have a foreign key here... good luck with that, buddy.”)

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i understand can you elaborate and show your sql statements?
if i understand correctly, ( which i may not ) your foreign key would just be blank if you did not have a value for that field, why would it error out?